# How to change text color of range selected using react-date-range?

Tags: reactjs, react-date-range

Can I change text color of date range selected with any properties available in react-date-range?
[screenshot1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UBYEo.png)
[screenshot2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/g2Vbv.png)

I am using react-date-range and react.js package.

i tried with custom styling but unable to get appropriate result

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Hi you have a rangeColors props in README.MD of this package

[Link to readme.md](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-date-range)

```
 const selectionRange = {
      startDate: new Date(),
      endDate: new Date(),
      key: 'selection',
    }
    return (
      <DateRangePicker
        ranges={[selectionRange]}
        onChange={this.handleSelect}
        rangeColors=["#40c72e"]
       />
```

you can add other colors, probably for multiples items or selections, same of ranges props